# How to find the potential function of this vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> $\vec G = \frac{3 y}{9 x^2 + y^2}\,\vec i + \frac{-3 x}{9 x^2 + y^2}\,\vec j$  is gradient vector fields on some domain (not necessarily the whole plane) by finding a potential function.
>
> For $\vec G$, the potential function is $g(x,y)$ =

I calculate many times, still cannot find the correct answer, anyone helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every domain exclude origin:
$$\vec G = \frac{3 y}{9 x^2 + y^2}\,\vec i + \frac{-3 x}{9 x^2 + y^2}\,\vec j=\nabla\left(-\arctan\dfrac{y}{3x}\right)$$